# "|=" what does this mean and what is this called? (c++)

Tags: c++, operators

```
void show_node_names()   { display_flags |= ShowNodeNames; } // what is "|="?
```

I'm not sure what "|=" does or what it's called.
Any help?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: I've updated your question to refer to `|=` consistently (you had `/=` in a couple of places). Please check that it says what it should now.

Comment: For many operators, there's a corresponding compound assignment operator whose symbol ends with `=`. For example, `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x + y`, except that `x` is only evaluated once. But not all operators have compound assignment operators (there's no `&&=`), and not all operators ending in `=` are compound assignments (`<=` is less-than-or-equal-to, not a compound less-than assignment).

Answer (score 4):

That statement is a bitwise or assignment.

It is equivalent to doing `display_flags = display_flags | ShowNodeNames`.

In particular, it will set every bit in  `display_flags` to `1` if the corresponding bit in `ShowNodeNames` is `1`.

Answer (score 3):

The `|=` operator is a compound assignment operator like `+=` or `*=`, but using the bitwise OR operator. The line

```
display_flags |= ShowNodeNames;
```

is equivalent to

```
display_flags = display_flags | ShowNodeNames;
```

If you haven't seen the bitwise OR operator, you should read up on it for more details. If you're familiar with it, then you can think of `display_flags |= ShowNodeNames;` as a way of saying "make all the bits set in `ShowNodeNames` also set in `display_flags`."

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

`|` (which can also be spelt `bitor`) is the *bitwise or* operator. It combines the bits of each operand so that each bit of the output is set if the corresponding bit of either operand is set. Compare this with the *bitwise and* operator, `&` or `bitand`, where each bit is set of the corresponding bit of *both* operands is set.

`|=` (or `or_eq`) is the corresponding assignment operator. As with all compound assignment operators, `a |= b` is equivalent to `a = a | b`, except that `a` is only evaluated once. Its effect is to set each bit in `a` that's set in `b`, and leave the other bits unchanged.